# Calculating surface elevation from DEM of pit and known volume with which it is being filled using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, dem, spatial-analyst

I am using ArcMap 10.1.

I have a DEM of a pit.

I have a known volume of material that I want to put in the pit.

I want to know what the elevation of the flat surface of this material will be once it is all in the pit.

There are a lot of tools for volume calculation that ArcGIS Desktop offers, but none seem to relate to this.

What springs to mind is to iterate through a set of constant raster values and see which most closely matches my known volume when I use each constant raster with the DEM in the "cut/fill" tool.

Comment: I had this problem a while back, and ended up doing as you describe. It wasn't too much work, but ofc an automatic method would be easier.

Comment: Better algorithms are described at http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/6486.